# how to add tax fees to transactions/transfers and Use fees toward liquidity

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, ether, binance-smart-chain

We have decided to launch a crypto token in support of new social streaming platform. And we would like to be able to add a tax fee that will be added to the liquidity of the token itself on pancake swap.

Right Now the contract is very simple. And as we develop it further before its initial launch we want to have some key features. And charging a tax fee to add to the liquidity of the token is the most important

We would like to charge an eight percent (8%) tax fee. So that four percent (4%) will be equally distributed to all holders/users/wallets that already have the token and the other four percent (4%) will go to the liquidity of the token. Please help US

```
 pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

 import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin- 
 contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

 contract OURTOKENNAME is ERC20 {
  constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public ERC20 ("ourTokenName", "OTK "){
    _mint(msg.sender,initialSupply);
  }
 }
```